# Programmatically enable Github Pages for a repository

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages, github-api

Is there any way to enable Github pages through the api?
Not requesting a page build, I mean the initial enabling of the feature and pointing to a branch.

Comment: i want to do the same but i am using master, not gh-pages. the api wont let me update page information if github pages isnt already enabled. what can i do?: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/pages/#update-information-about-a-pages-site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to push content to the remote git repository.
You have to differentiate between a **User-Page** (username.github.io) and a **Project-Page** (username.github.io/projectname)

#### User-Page:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/username.github.io
cd username.github.io

echo "Hello World" > index.html

git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

#### Project-Page:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/repository.git
cd repository

git branch gh-pages
git checkout gh-pages
echo "Hello World" > index.html

git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin gh-pages
```

Comment: Thanks! I need it for a project page, the gh-pages did the trick.